# WPF datatable read only without adding rows

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatable

I have a data table in my view and I'm binding its ReadOnly attribute to a bool on the view model, my problem is that I don't want to allow adding new rows, just to edit the current row that is already been shown. How can I do that?

Comment: I assume your using a datagrid? Make sure 'CanUserAddRows' = false If the datatable itself is set to readonly then the whole table will be readonly. If you want certain things editable and other things readonly then you will need to use datagridcolumns in which then you can specify whether or not its readonly or not instead of setting the whole grid to readonly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that worked! thank you! 

I have another question in that same topic, I want to hide one of the columns i tried to use myGrid.Columns[6].Visibility = Visibility.hidden

But there is no visibility attribute in the myGrid.Columns[6].